# How to approach JMX Client polling

Tags: java, jmx, instrumentation

recently I dove into the world of JMX, trying to instrument our applications, and expose some operations through a custom JMXClient. The work of figuring out how to instrument the classes without having to change much about our existing code is already done. I accomplished this using a DynamicMBean implementation. Specifically, I created a set of annotations, which we decorate our classes with. Then, when objects are created (or initialized if they are used as static classes), we register them with our MBeanServer through a static class, that builds a dynamicMBean for the class and registers it. This has worked out beautifully when we just use JConsole or VisualVM. We can execute operations and view the state of fields all like we should be able to. My question is more geared toward creating a semi-realtime JMXClient like JConsole.

The biggest problem I'm facing here is how to make the JMXClient report the state of fields in as close to realtime as I can reasonably get, without having to modify the instrumented libraries to push notifications (eg. in a setter method of some class, set the field, then fire off a JMX notification). We want the classes to be all but entirely unaware they are being instrumented. If you check out JConsole while inspecting an attribute, there is a refresh button at the bottom of the the screen that refreshes the attribute values. The value it displays to you is the value retrieved when that attribute was loaded into the view, and wont ever change without using the refresh button. I want this to happen on its own.

I have written a small UI which shows some data about connection states, and a few field on some instrumented classes. In order to make those values reflect the current state, I have a Thread which spins in the background. Every second or so the thread attempts to get the current values of the fields I'm interested in, then the UI gets updated as a result. I don't really like this solution very much, as its tricky to write the logic that updates the underlying models. And even trickier to update the UI in a way that doesn't cause strange bugs (using Swing).

I could also write an additional section of the JMXAgent in our application side, with a single thread that runs through the list of DynamicMBeans that have been registered, determines if the values of their attributes have change, then pushes a notification(s). This would move the notification logic out of the instrumented libraries, but still puts more load on the applications :(.

I'm just wondering if any of you have been in this position with JMX, or something else, and can guide me in the right direction for a design methodology for the JMXClient or really any other advice that could make this solution more elegant than the one I have.

Any suggestions you guys have would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: If you graph values in jconsole, it will auto-refresh them every couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the entities then something is going to have to poll them.  Either your `JMXAgent` or the JMX client is going to have to request the beans every so often.  There is no way for you to get around this performance hit although since you are calling a bunch of gets, I don't think it's going to be very expensive.  Certainly your `JMXAgent` would be better than the JMX client polling all of the time.  But if the client is polling all of the beans anyway then the cost may be exactly the same.

You would not need to do the polling if the objects could call the agent to say that they have been changed or if they supported some sort of `isDirty()` method.

In our systems, we have a metrics system that the various components used.  Each of the classes incremented their own metric and it was the metrics that were wired into a persister.  You could request the metric values using JMX or persist them to disk or the wire.  By using a `Metric` type, then there was separation between the entity that was doing the counting and the entities that needed access to all of the metric values.

By going to a registered `Metric` object type model, your GUI could then query the `MetricRegistrar` for all of the metrics and display them via JMX, HTML, or whatever.  So your entities would just do `metric.increment()` or `metric.set(...)` and the GUI would query the metric whenever it needed the value.

Hope something here helps.

Comment: I'm resisting the inevitable here :(. Can you recommend a design methodology that lends itself well to asynchronous model updates for a GUI app? I'm pretty good at making solutions to small problems, but judgement on design methodologies overall is poor...

Comment: I've added some more details to my answer @MarkW.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll have to think more about this Metric object type model (I believe its very similar to what I'm already doing). Because I believe you to be right about resource needs being roughly equal between the JMX Agent and Client side polling mechanisms, and there being no way around it, I'll accept this answer as well. Appreciate it Gray.

Answer (score 1):

Being efficient here means staying inside the mbean server that contains the beans you're looking at. What you want is a way to *convert* the mbeans that don't know how to issue notifications into mbeans that *do*.

For watching numeric and string attributes, you can use the standard mbeans in the monitor package. Instantiate those *in* the mbean server that contains the beans you actually want to watch, and then set the properties appropriately. You can do this without adding code to the target because the monitor package is standard in the JVM. The monitor beans will watch the objects you select for changes and will emit change notifications only when actual changes are observed. Use setGranularityPeriod to tell the monitor beans how often to look at the target.

Once the monitor beans are in place, just register for the MonitorNotifications that will be created upon change.

Answer (score 0):

not a solution per se but you can simplify your polling-event translator JMXAgent implementation using  spring integration. It has something called JMX Attribute Polling Channel which seems to fulfill your need. [example here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jmx)